# Create a Custom User Control that Uses the ID I give it and honors ClientIDMode="Static"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, webusercontrol

I have a few Custom Controls I built in C# for my Web App. Also I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YearsTextBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="MutualExpert.Controls.YearsTextBox"  %>
<div class="input-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" CssClass="form-control text-right" />
    <div class="input-group-addon">Years</div>
</div>
```

Calling it from the ASPX page I want to use it on:

```
<cc:YearsTextBox runat="server" ID="tbDamageLife" />
```

I want the Control to be rendered on the page as "tbDamageLife"

**What I Tried:**

If I specify ClientIDMode="Static" on  then I get the ID="tb" :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input name="ctl00$cpMain$tbDamageLife$tb" id="tb" class="form-control text-right" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-addon">Years</div>
</div>
```

If I don't then I get ID="ctl00_cpMain_tbDamageLife_tb" :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input name="ctl00$cpMain$tbDamageLife$tb" id="ctl00_cpMain_tbDamageLife_tb" class="form-control text-right" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-addon">Years</div>
</div>
```

I just want it to render tbDamageLife, the ID I am giving it.

This is a tricky one, I need these to be static for JS to access it to do calculations. It is necessary.  I would work around it if I could but I simply cannot.

Comment: I am outputting multiple controls gathering "Years"  so there is an obvious issue if they all come out "tb" (key already exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The team and I found an alternative way that end up being a lot less code on the HTML and JS sides of it and IMHO a lot easier to remember and work with for the team.

Simply speaking, add a CSS class name.  Example:

```
<cc:YearsTextBox runat="server" ID="tbDamageLife" CssClass="tbDamageLife" />
```

In the user control:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Class
    /// </summary>
    public string CssClass
    {
        get { return tb.CssClass; }
        set
        {
            // we need to make sure that form-control is always part of the Class
            if (value.Contains("form-control"))
                tb.CssClass = value;
            else
                tb.CssClass += " " + value;
        }
    }
```

and in JS:

```
    case _ui.newlevel.select:
        $(".tbDamageLife").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 2):

A UserControl itself does not have an ID in html, only in code. So the best solution in your case would be to wrap the UserControl content inside a Panel and give that the ID `tbDamageLife`. That will become the `<div>` with the class `input-group`.

```
<asp:Panel ID="tbDamageLife" runat="server" CssClass="input-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" CssClass="form-control text-right" />
    <div class="input-group-addon">Years</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

And on the parent page

```
<cc:YearsTextBox runat="server" ID="tbDamageLife" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Will render as

```
<div id="tbDamageLife" class="input-group">
    <input name="ctl00$cpMain$tbDamageLife$tb" type="text" id="tb" class="form-control text-right" />
    <div class="input-group-addon">Years</div>
</div>
```

However if you should add multiple controls you will have duplicate ID's.

Or you could simply do the following if you do not need the functionality of the Panel Control.

```
<div id="tbDamageLife" class="input-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" CssClass="form-control text-right" />
    <div class="input-group-addon">Years</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work but had added JS code that would have to have been written to find the children of the panel and would not have always worked 100% each time in all situations of bootstrap form formatting strategies with the same JS.

I appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The user control acts as a "placeholder" and is replaced by its actual contents when the calling page is rendered:

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="tbDamageLife$tb" type="text" id="tbDamageLife_tb" class="form-control text-right">
        <div class="input-group-addon">Years</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In the above example, note that there is no element with `tbDamageLife` id. Rather, the user control id is used to produce unique identification for the contained `TextBox` (which is rendered). So, this is pretty standard behavior and a correct one, too.

Nevertheless, you can access the `TextBox` of the user control from javascript using `ClientID`, for example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc:YearsTextBox runat="server" ID="tbDamageLife" />
        <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="btnOK_Click()" />
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnOK_Click() {
        var ucTb = document.getElementById('<%= tbDamageLife.FindControl("tb").ClientID %>');

        console.log(ucTb.value);
    }
</script>
```

IMHO, this is the "safest" way to do it meaning that you are actually using the `tbDamageLife` id from the server code which *does known* about it.

Comment: This would work fine but ended up adding a lot more JS, and would of made me have to create global variables to access the ClientID from a script (not inline js to the HTML).  This would not have scaled as seamlessly.